# In JetBrains Rider, is there a way to run compound run / debug configurations without closing running projects?

Tags: rider

I have a bunch of compound run / debug configurations, each containing about 20 profiles, a lot of which overlap.

Every time I ran a compound configuration where some projects were already running I had to press the *cancel* button about 15 times in order to prevent already running projects from stopping.

Today I noticed the *Don't show this again* checkbox, so I checked it and clicked *cancel*, expecting it to always *cancel*.  Now, instead of keeping all my projects running, it stops all of them.

How do I get this dialog back, or switch it to not stop projects that are already running?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from Rider Support:

To restore the notification, open the file *.idea/workspace.xml* from your project root, and set the value to *true* in the following parameter:

```xml
<property name="restartRequiresConfirmation" value="false" />
```

Comment: this isn't actually an answer to your question

Comment: @KeithNicholas setting the value to true does allow me to run without closing running projects.  I do also have to click "Cancel" when running them though.  If I add that to my answer, would you accept it?